# How to wrap div elements around another div element

Tags: css, html

This must be an oft-answered question, but my google-foo fails me.
Take a look at the pretty diagram:

```
+------------+ +--+
|    nav     | |  |
+------------+ |s |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |i |
|:)| |:)| |:)| |d |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |e |
               |  |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |  |
|:)| |:)| |:)| |  |
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+ 

+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|:)| |:)| |:)| |:)|
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
```

It represents a container in which there's a nav div, a sidebar div and lots of little divs containing images and text.

What I'm trying to achieve is, no matter the height of the sidebar, the image divs will appear in nice rows with as many columns in a given row as will fit.  They'll nicely wrap under the sidebar.

I've tried a million different ways, but the image divs either start below the bottom of the sidebar or else row 2 will have 3 divs and then a fourth, pushed down by the sidebar.

```
+------------+ +--+
|    nav     | |  |
+------------+ |s |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |i |
|:)| |:)| |:)| |d |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |e |
               |  |
+--+ +--+ +--+ |  |
|:)| |:)| |:)| +--+
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
               |:(|
               +--+
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
|:(| |:(| |:(| |:(|
+--+ +--+ +--+ +--+
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is this even possible and, if so, how?

Comment: what is this and where is this used??

Comment: what do you mean, gov? have i missed some pertinent information, do you think?

Comment: no i am casually asking what is the above html , where is it used i never say something lie that.

Comment: it's an online store under development and the smiley faces represent product thumbnails. what more can I tell you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/antiflu/kwvcZ/

The idea behind it is that you want to float the sidebar (place it out of the flow). The nav bar and the dummy item should be block elements in the flow (following the flow, but with a line break before) and the images should be inline elements in the flow (filling up the rest of the page like text would).

Source code HTML:

```
<img class="sidebar" src="http://dummyimage.com/123x340">
<img class="nav" src="http://dummyimage.com/340x123">
<div class="break">Dummy</div>
<img class="i1 top1" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100">
<img class="i1" src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100">
(etc...)
```

Source code CSS:

```
img.nav {float: left;}
img.sidebar {float:right;}
div.break {clear: left;}
img.i1 {display:inline; padding: 5px;}
```

PS. I did it with IMG tags but you can just as well use DIVs.

---

**Update**: In order for the image elements to be blocks in their own right in which you can use layout etc. you can use `display: inline-block` instead of inline for the i1-type elements:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/antiflu/nqNeZ/

This works neatly on my Chrome, but you will run into a couple of [cross-browser issues](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) for IE and Firefox 2. However those issues can be tackled by following [these](http://www.aaronrussell.co.uk/blog/cross-browser-support-for-inline-block/) or [these](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) guidelines.

Comment: that's really interesting littlegreen, thank you. just to clarify, this can be done with div elements instead of img elems? i'm off to try it out! -edit: oh I see you answered that already!

Comment: Yes, except with the "i1" elements you should be mindful that anything you put into it will be inline as well.

Comment: +1 for a working solution but the "images" can't have any padding/margin/border.

Comment: yes, the things i want to put into the "i1" elements are indeed causing me problems - if i give, say, a span a relative position and negative left to try and pull it back into the "i1" element then it only works if that span hadn't already wrapped to the next line. more fiddling needed.

Comment: Some googling and fiddling and an updated answer is there... I don't quite follow your span story but this might fix it.

Comment: littlegreen, I really appreciate the effort you put into answering this question and for doing my fiddling for me; you're awesome. I didn't know inline-block was even a valid value for display, but, using the resources you pointed me to, it works like a charm!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I learn new stuff here every day, glad to help you out with my knowledge. And it's always good to have a nice puzzle to sharpen the rusty HTML skills ;)